# Reducing computation for distance matrix for nxn points

Tags: sparse-matrix, computation, haversine

I have a dataframe with latitude and longitude points (apprx 1m).

I want to compute haversine distance for each point against all other points.

example:

```
import haversine

lat1 = 40.5; lat2 = 42; long1 = -90; long2 = -93
print( haversine.distance((lat1, long1), (lat2, long2)) )
```

But computing 1mx1m computation won't make sense, as for each loop, we need 1 computation less than previous, as e.g. distance of point 1 from 2 will be same as point 2 from 1.

How can I reduce my computations for each step?

Answer (score 0):

Use vectorized approach:

Demo:

```
In [105]: from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

In [106]: dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

In [107]: df
Out[107]:
    latitude   longitude
0  38.550420 -121.391416
1  38.473501 -121.490186
2  38.657846 -121.462101
3  38.506774 -121.426951
4  38.637448 -121.384613

In [108]: earth_radius = 6371
     ...: D = dist.pairwise(np.radians(df), np.radians(df)) * earth_radius
     ...:

In [109]: D
Out[109]:
array([[  0.        ,  12.12461135,  13.43188915,   5.75400608,   9.69511663],
       [ 12.12461135,   0.        ,  20.64315089,   6.63158885,  20.41101851],
       [ 13.43188915,  20.64315089,   0.        ,  17.07403265,   7.10128697],
       [  5.75400608,   6.63158885,  17.07403265,   0.        ,  14.9892082 ],
       [  9.69511663,  20.41101851,   7.10128697,  14.9892082 ,   0.        ]])
```